# Muhammad al-Idrisi lake Victoria map 12th Century

Tags: maps, lakes

Wikipedia and many other sources state along the lines of, "An excellent map, known as the Muhammad al-Idrisi map from the calligrapher (sic) who developed it and dated from the 1160s, clearly depicts an accurate representation of Lake Victoria, and attributes it as the source of the Nile."

But when I look at the [maps online](http://www.alrahalah.com/2015/01/al-idrisi-12th-century-ce-5th-century-ah-geographer-and-cartographer/) I cannot depict Lake Victoria on his maps. Can anyone show me where Muhammad al-Idrisi depicts Lake Victoria on his 12th Century Maps?

I got the images below from http://www.alrahalah.com/2015/01/al-idrisi-12th-century-ce-5th-century-ah-geographer-and-cartographer/

On the top map I cannot depict sub-Saharan Africa as this map appears to be mostly North Africa, Asia, and Europe and just misses Lake Victoria.

On the lower map (it says north is down) I suspect the yellow circle is Lake Victoria but this is just a guess.

[image: Map 1]
[image: Map 2]

Comment: I wonder whether this might not be a question suitable for researching/asking at the [history.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Ill give it a try.

Comment: @PolyGeo but I did enjoy applying the Idrisi tag here.

Comment: Sorry, I had to remove it because you are not using IDRISI Selva software in your question.  Another site which may be more suited to your question about historical maps may be the [earthscience.se] Stack Exchange because I think it is about general geography/cartography rather than GIS.  Although their on-topic page suggests it may be off-topic there too.